# How to compute Cook's distances for generalized least squares models

Tags: r, nlme

Does anyone know how to compute Cooks' distances for a [gls](/questions/tagged/gls) class object (obtained through the [nlme](/questions/tagged/nlme) package)? The standard cooks.distance function only seems to work for lm class objects.

Comment: We could keep your question here if you would include an explanation for non-`R` users concerning what statistical procedures the functions `gls` and `lm` are implementing. That would make it accessible to many more people who could help you.  If you already know the formulas in the generalized least squares setting and just want `R` code, then please flag this question for migration to [SO].

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for specific code, so I've flagged it now to be migrated to Stack Overflow.